# unable to pass List of Id from Visualforce page to lightning component

Tags: lightning

I have a custom list button on campaign. On select of Campaign records, I need to send the selected Ids to the List type attribute of component. 
I can do that but when I am iterating over it's ids its taking each character as a list element.

```
$Lightning.use("c:CampaignDedupApp", function() {

         $Lightning.createComponent("c:CampaignDedupComp",
         {
            CampId : "[701XXXXX90,701XXXXXX12]"

         },
```

Component

Code

```
<aura:component controller="CampaignMemberDedupe">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.myAction}"/>
<aura:attribute name="CampId" type="List" />
```

Output:-
[
7
0
1
x
x
x
x
x
x
]
[
7
0
1
x
x
x
]

Unable to get Id as a single element of list.

Comment: Can you show more of your code, sounds like you're iterating over a string, ie looping through characters

Comment: I have added my code above where it is iterating over attribute named <aura:attribute name="CampId" type="List"

Comment: Have you tried with Array as the type instead of List

Comment: try String[] or Object[] as the type

Answer (score 1):

Updated Answer-

```
$Lightning.use("c:CampaignDedupApp", function() {

     $Lightning.createComponent("c:CampaignDedupComp",
     {
        CampId : ["701XXXXX90","701XXXXXX12"]

     },
```

Try this

Comment: Already tried but no luck